# iOS Localizations mess up the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an iOS Application that supports different languages, which uses LTR Storyboard and RTL Storyboard, and reads from Plists. When I run the app on my Device with English iOS Version, everything looks perfect when switching between the languages. But when I change the iPhone OS Language to RTL languages. The UI is messed up.

This happens especially when I enable Localizations to change the app name on home screen.

Any idea why does that happen?

The whole menu is messed up for example, it's to the left side while it should be to the right side, and the menu items icons must be to the left and the labels to the right.

RTL Language on LTR iOS Language Device i.e English
  [image]

RTL Language on RTL iOS Language Device
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @SaintThread I have edited my post

Comment: Did you add the label leading to parenview and trailing to imageview?

Comment: @SaintThread yes of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are use leading and trailing constraint.
In a LTR environment leading means left while in an RTL environment, leading means right.
This is Apple way of helpings us to deal with RTL/LTR easily :[ in your case, not so much... 
To disable this behaviour, change the semantic attribute of your views.

> Semantic Content
>
> If you lay out your views using leading and trailing constraints, the
>   views automatically flip positions when switching between
>   left-to-right languages (like English) and right-to-left languages
>   (like Arabic). However, some interface elements should not change
>   their position based on the reading direction. For example, buttons
>   that are based on physical directions (up, down, left, and right)
>   should always stay in the same relative orientation.
>
> The view’s semanticContentAttribute property determines whether the
>   view’s content should flip when switching between left-to-right and
>   right-to-left languages.
>
> In interface builder, set the Semantic option in the Attribute
>   inspector. If the value is Unspecified, the view’s content flips with
>   the reading direction. If it is set to Spatial, Playback, or Force
>   Left-to-Right, the content is always laid out with the leading edges
>   to the left and trailing edges to the right. Force Right-to-Left
>   always lays out the content with the leading edges to the right and
>   the trailing edges to the left.

Comment: How do you add alignment instead of leading/trailing ?

Comment: You have to the rightAnchor / leftAnchor instead of the trailingAnchor / leadingAnchor. I've edited my response to quote a chatpter of Apple doc

Comment: why they think everything in our life is flipped? calm down apple, google, just our text rtf not our world.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are already using [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/), 
Make sure you have done the following

**Remove fixed width constraints**. Allow views that display localized text to resize. If you use fixed width constraints, localized text may appear cropped in some languages.

**Use intrinsic content sizes**. The default behavior for text fields and labels is to resize automatically. If a view is not adjusting to the size of localized text, select the view and choose Editor > Size To Fit Content.

**Use leading and trailing attributes**. When adding constraints, use the attributes leading and trailing for horizontal constraints. For left-to-right languages, such as English, the attributes leading and trailing are equivalent to left and right. For right-to-left language, such as Hebrew or Arabic, leading and trailing are equivalent to right and left. The leading and trailing attributes are the default values for horizontal constraints.

**Pin views to adjacent views**. Pinning causes a domino effect. When one view resizes to fit localized text, other views do the same. Otherwise, views may overlap in some languages.

**Constantly test your layout changes**. Test your app using different language settings, as described in [Testing Your Internationalized App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW1).

**Don’t set the minimum size or maximum size of a window**. Let the window and its content view adjust to the size of the containing views, which may change when the language changes.

See [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW10)

Comment: Copied verbatim from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW10.

Comment: I have already followed these, and the constraints are set well.

Comment: The problem lies I believe in the leading and trailing attributes, how can that be fixed? @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

Probably a matters of constraints. In the storyboard, you can use the preview editor to get a .. well.. preview, of your UI in diffrent device size in different language.

[image]

Comment: No at all, the constraints are set well.